# Script execution failed error in aem groovy console

Tags: groovy, aem

I am trying to update sling:resourceType and node name in aem using groovy script. Everytime when I run the script I am getting "Script execution failed error".

```
List<String> pages= new ArrayList<String>();
getNode('/content').recurse {rootNode ->
        if (rootNode.hasProperty('property')) {
            pages.add(rootNode.getParent().getPath());
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you check logs? More information needed.

Answer (score 0):

@rmac, your script seems to be fine, Please try to navigate to locale level and execute the script.

I am assuming, it is getting timed out. Iterating through '/content' will take lot of time and might time out sometimes.
Try updating your path to '/content/sitename/en' or even deep in the hierarchy if you have a lot of content.

Please share the complete error in case if it is not working.

Comment: I wonder if `/content` has `jcr:root` parent or that's null in this case...

Answer (score 0):

If it still helps:

```
  import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver
  import javax.jcr.Node
  import javax.jcr.Session

   session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
  Node node = session.getNode("/content/we- 
    retail/us/en/jcr:content/root/hero_image");

   node.getSession().move(node.getPath(), node.getParent().getPath() + "/" + 
    "test");
   node.setProperty("prop", "value");

 save()
```